# How to transfer large files from Google App Engine to an external server

Tags: google-app-engine

I need my application in Google App Engine to be able to transfer files up to 25MB size to an external server via web service. How can this be done?

I need to do it the other way to, transfer a large file from an external server to Google App Engine. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You could just upload the file from your external server to Blobstore (generate an upload URL, have ext server POST large file there), and also serve it from Blobstore.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending files you can't do it with [URLFetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/#PHP_Quotas_and_limits) as the request size limit is 10MB.

You can do it with sockets, where you can fsockopen() directly to the target web service and then write as much data as you want over the socket.

For retrieving a large file, you can upload up to 100TB files directly to Google Cloud Storage using [createUploadURL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/) if you want you app to act as a service, otherwise you can retrieve files up to 32MB using [URLFetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/#PHP_Quotas_and_limits).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the problem that we have with Sockets API is that, as far as we know, it is in Preview Status and do not yet provide SLA-level guaranties. This is critical for us. There is no other way to do it?

Comment: For that matter the PHP runtime is still in preview status as well. I think sockets is the best way if you want to put/post > 10MB to an external service.

Comment: Ahh just noticed this not a PHP question ;) - Still, use sockets for any runtime would be the best way.

Comment: @StuartLangley createUploadURL is not longer supported for PHP 7+, there is some alternative?